# how to pass data from recyclerView to adapter for dynamic layout

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am making dynamic recyclerView with multiple layouts. I have made three to four layout which should be changed dynamically according to the style type id. Now I am getting style Id in recyclerview and how I can pass this value to the adapter.

**here is my snapshot**
[image: here is my snapshot]

here is my code form which i am getting style Type Id:

```
int StyleTypeId = object.getInt("StyleTypeID");
```

here is my adapter code:

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = null;
    if (viewType == 1) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rv_electronic_category, parent, false);
    }else if (viewType == 2){
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rv_latest_product, parent, false);
    }
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (holder.getItemViewType() == 1){
        holder.setData(products.get(position));
    }else if (holder.getItemViewType() == 2) {
        holder.setLatestProductData(products.get(position));
    }
}
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return 2;
}
```

my problem is that how I can pass the style type Id from JSON object to adapter runtime

Comment: Make it global and pass it to adapter constructor.

Comment: how can you suggext me this

Comment: Create another variable `type` inside your products object class and according to object type set your dynamic layout.

Comment: not working fine

Answer (score 0):

create your adapter like this

```
int StyleTypeId = object.getInt("StyleTypeID");
YourAdapter adapter = new YourAdapter(StyleTypeId);
```

then inside your adapter

```
class YourAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<YourViewHolder> {
    private int styledId;
    YourAdapter(int styleId) { this.styleId = styleId; }
}
```

and in onCreateViewHolder() you can use the styleId to create appropriate view.

Answer (score 0):

```
int StyleTypeId = object.getInt("StyleTypeID");
X adapter = new X(StyleTypeId);
```

then your adapter class add the following snippet:

```
private int viewType;
        X(int styleId) { this.viewType = styleId; }
```

In the getItemViewType method return your viewtype instead of static variable

```
 @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return viewType;
    }
```